# How can I use images instead of radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have a div of radio buttons:

```
            <div class="radio-line">
          <label>
            <img src="img/black.jpeg" />
            <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="1"/>
          </label>
          <label>
            <img src="img/blue.jpg" />
            <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="2"/>
          </label>
        </div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  padding: 2vw;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:active {
  opacity:0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + img {
  border: 20px solid rgb(228, 207, 94);
}
```

When I hover over a square, the square opacity will change, but nothing happens when I click on the square (when it should be "checked", a border should surround it). I've been playing around with different divs and labels, but nothing is working.

```css
img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  padding: 2vw;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

img:hover {
  opacity:0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:active {
  opacity:0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + img {
  border: 20px solid rgb(228, 207, 94);
}
```

```html
              <label>
                <img src="img/black.jpeg" />
                <input type="radio" name="choice-1" value="1"/>
              </label>
              <label>
                <img src="img/blue.jpg" />
                <input type="radio" name="choice-1" value="1"/>
              </label>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can used the :checked pseudo-class and sibling selectors to achieve the effect.

So first thing is to move into a structure where inputs are siblings of the labels instead of descendants, and include a "for" attribute that links them

```css
img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  padding: 2vw;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

img:hover {
  opacity:0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:active {
  opacity:0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
  border: 20px solid rgb(228, 207, 94);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choose-1" value="1"/>
<label for="choose-1">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200/200/" />
</label>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choose-2" value="2"/>
<label for="choose-2">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200/200/" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to set an onClick function on the images. Assign the images a custom class e.g: radioImage and in jQuery:

```
$( ".radioImage" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).css("border", "20px solid rgb(228, 207, 94)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `for` property of `label` to the name of `input` you want.
In this case, it maybe looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-1" value="1"/>
<label for="choice-1">
    <img src="img/black.jpeg" />
</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-2" value="1"/>
<label for="choice-2">
    <img src="img/blue.jpg" />
</label>
```

Comment: that's still not valid HTML, and won't work. the input can't be inside the label, and the "for" atribute should reference input's "id", not "name". And should be unique.

Comment: just wanna say.. I was not the downvoter. actually just voted up since you fixed it

Comment: @FacundoCorradini it doesn't matter, thanks for your help!